# Deleting a Registry value's Parent Key

Tags: powershell

We’re currently upgrading to a new Wireless system and with that we’re pushing out the SSID through a GPO. However, we would like to remove the existing SSID/Profile from the system, which isn’t an issue with simply using "`netsh wlan delete profile name`". The problem we’re having is removing these profiles from our user’s "`Lenovo Access Connections`" which is managing most (if not all) user’s various network profiles. If it’s deleted with the netsh, the user can simply open up Access Connections and it will recreate that profile within Windows.
We cannot simply delete the profiles since each user can name our company network with whatever nickname they want within the program. That being said, I’ve found where these profiles are stored within the registry.

Lenovo Access Connections :

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations
```

This is where the problem lies, I cannot figure a means to search within the `Locations` folder for our SSID, then delete it’s main key. It is currently laid out like this:

```
\Locations\(Custom Profile Name)\AdptList\Adpt00\
```

Within the `Adpt00` Key there is a `Reg_SZ` with the name of `m_szSsid` with it’s value = `Our Network`’s SSID. So, basically I’m looking to search ALL of `\Locations` and if any of the `m_szSsid` within the `Adpt00` Key for each of the varying Profiles exists.. delete the entire Profile from `\Locations`, and yes some of our user’s have multiple Profile’s setup for the same Network SSID for a reason unknown to me.

This is what I have so far

```
$LACKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations"
$LACProfileKey = Get-ChildItem $LACKey -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
   If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match "m_szSsid")
      {
      $_.PsPath
      }
  }
```

This returns the only profile under `\Locations` for the current test machine (which only contains one matching profile), but from here I'm unsure of how to expand the `m_szSsid` for each matching Wireless Profile found to ensure it matches our `SSID`. Then from there Delete the Parent profile folder under `\Locations\`

**Edit:**

I've made some changes

```
$LACKey = 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations'
$LACProfileKey = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\$LACKey" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
If(( Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match "m_szSsid") {
$_.PsPath 
ForEach-Object {
If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $LACProfileKey -Name m_szSsid).m_szSsid -match "<Company SSID HERE>") {
$ssIDKey = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $LACProfileKey $_.PSParentPath).PSParentPath
}
}
}
}
```

But I am returning this error

```
Get-ItemProperty : Property Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access C
onnections\Locations\<Company SSID HERE>\AdptList does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Con
nections\Locations\HYDAC-NA\AdptList\Adpt00.
At line:6 char:29
+ $ssIDKey = (Get-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path $LACProfileKey $_.PSParentPath).PSParentPath
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...ID ERE>\AdptList:String)   [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgume
   ntException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :    System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPr
  opertyCommand
```

I would appreciate any further guidance on this,I'm sure it is obvious I am quite a Powershell Novice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name "m_szSsid"
```

You also have `$_.PSPath` and also `$_.PSParentPath`, with this information, you should be able to use `Remove-Item` on the appropriate regkey

Comment: thank you for the tip, I have updated my original post with my "progress" with these suggestions.