# Finding a value in the registry, then deleting the parent key

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I need to search the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` registry key and look for a value in one of the subkeys.  Once it is located, I need to delete the parent key.  I'd like to do this in powershell or WMI if possible.

Does anyone have any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Please show us examples of what you have tried or issues you have with your current coding. This has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789830/deleting-a-registry-values-parent-key)

Answer (score -1):

My favorite Technet blogger Ed Wilson has a nice introductory to working with the registry in PowerShell in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/07/use-the-powershell-registry-provider-to-simplify-registry-access.aspx). That should get you started.